# Black underline when hover over photos and buttons using Instagram Feed plugin

Tags: hover, instagram, shadow, underline

I have installed the **Instagram Feed** plugin to display photos from my instagram account as well as showing the more photos button and follow us button under the photos. Everything looks great except that I have a **black thick underline** at the bottom of my photos and buttons when hover over them. The color of the buttons are grey and the text color is white.

I have tried several CSS codes to add to in the Customise/Additional CSS to change hover color, box-shadow color, background color but nothing seems to work. I’m building my website on the desktop server so it is not live yet.

Comment: Show us your code. Otherwhise its not possible to help you.

Comment: I have tried many for example: .entry-content a { box-shadow: #767676; }

Comment: When I hover over the pic and buttons and inspect this is one of the texts: 
}
#sb_instagram a, #sb_instagram a:active, #sb_instagram a:focus, #sb_instagram a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}
form.customize-unpreviewable, form.customize-unpreviewable input, form.customize-unpreviewable select, form.customize-unpreviewable button, a.customize-unpreviewable, area.customize-unpreviewable {
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
} Does this mean I'm not allowed to make the changes I would like to?